# Check unique hash_key in dynamodb - python

Tags: python, boto, amazon-dynamodb

i'm trying to check existence of an hash_key in dynamodb with boto (i can not update my filed if exist)
i've try with query

```
   for i in self.table.query(hask_key=[value]):
      print i['url']
```

But i miss an argument (???).
I've try with scan but i need to check my hash_key, not attributes.

I've try with get_item but i cannot manage the response if hash_key does not exist.

Any advice?

I've play with redis and it have exist method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than doing a query operation, you should just attempt to retrieve the item using `get_item`.  If it exists, the item will be returned.  If not, the call will raise a `DynamoDBKeyNotFoundError` which you can catch.  So, something like:

```
def exists(hash_key):
    try:
        item = self.table.get_item(hash_key=<hash key>...)
    except boto.dynamodb.exceptions.DynamoDBKeyNotFoundError:
        item = None
    return item
```

would return None if the hash didn't exist and would return the item if it did exist.

Comment: Is there a cheaper way to do this than to pay the full cost of retrieving the item?

Answer (score 4):

Just ended up on this page after a google search. Here's a 2020 update:

The API behaviour has changed and is returning either '*the item*' or '*nothing*', but won't raise an exception:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.get_item

Here is an example of how to use get_item to query for a single item:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html#getting-an-item

And this SOF answer addresses the specific problem of checking for the existence of an item in a DDB table:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48589589/512155