# "The provided key element does not match the schema" error when getting an item from DynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

This is the table partition key setting
[image]

The table content
[image]

When I tried to get an item from the table, it prints this error

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred
>   (ValidationException) when calling the GetItem operation: The provided
>   key element does not match the schema

This is my code

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('testDynamodb')
response = table.get_item(Key={'userId': "user2873"})
item = response['Item']
print(item)
```

Any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Your table schema has both hash key and sort key defined. When using DynamoDB GetItem you must provide both of them, here is an excerpt from [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html)

> For the primary key, you must provide all of the attributes. For
>   example, with a simple primary key, you only need to provide a value
>   for the partition key. For a composite primary key, you must provide
>   values for both the partition key and the sort key.

So given your example, here is how get_item parameters should look like:

```
response = table.get_item(Key={'userId': "user2873", 'createdAt': "1489376547"})
```

Comment: 'Your table schema has both hash key and partition key defined'—I kinda want to tag that with 'citation needed' . Can you explain how you can tell that from the code and image in the question?

Comment: @MichaelScheper Actually, the `hash key` and `partition key` are the same thing. Funny that no one noticed that before. So it should say 'Your table schema has both hash key and sort key defined.' Will fix this.

Comment: @MichaelScheper As for your question, you can tell that the schema has both partition (hash) key and sort key defined by looking at the first image (more precisely, at the `Primary partition key` and the `Primary sort key` fields)

Comment: Yep, now that you've made that correction (and now that I've played a bit more with Dynamo and gained slightly more experience ☺), it makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: does this mean that is impossible to query this table for all records which were createdAt a single value?  (all user's created on a certain date?)  That seems odd.  (noob to dynamodb)

Comment: @JasonMichael you can't do this with GetItem, you'll need to use Scan (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) Note that scan operation implies reading all records in a table, so it may work as a single time use, but if your app needs this more than once, consider adapting your table schema.

Answer (score 37):

One other thing that works is the following code below:

```
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key

result = table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('userId').eq('user2873')
    )
```

Answer (score 5):

I have also got the same issue.
The solution to this is :

While creating the Table, define only `usrID` in your `schema` as `Hash` Key. [I mean Single Primary Key]

Then you can call get item based on your `usrID`.
If you are defining `usrId` and `createdAt` in your Table `Schema` as `Hash` and `Sort` Key.[I mean composite primary key] You have to provide both while calling getItem.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error, but mine was an easy fix. My key ID (Product Id) called in my lambda function.py code wasn't the same as my DynamoDB partition key (Product_Id). so i had a make those few changes. You key and partition key in both the code and the table should always match. Hope this helps some too. :)

Answer (score -2):

I guess you don't have to put all the related attributes

in my case I only have one PK as col

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const connectionId = event.requestContext.connectionId;
  deleteConnectionId(connectionId).then(() => {
    callback(null, { statusCode: 200 , message: 'userId deleted'});
  });
};


function deleteConnectionId(connectionId) {
  return ddb
    .delete({ TableName: 'your table name', 
        Key: {
            userId : connectionId.toString() // userId is my PK in this case
         }
    } )
    .promise();
}
```