# Unable to access DynamoDB from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have created a lambda java project to get items from dynamoDB.But I am getting error while accessing.

Code that I wrote:

```
dbClient = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(dbClient);
Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("TokenSystem");
Item item = table.getItem("TokenId", 123456);
return item.toJSON();
```

Error getting in lambda console:

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: The provided key element does not match the schema (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 9OJVLPJHV011KLGKI20Q8QN2FNVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1658)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1322)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1072)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:745)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:719)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:701)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:669)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:651)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:515)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.doInvoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3609)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3578)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3567)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.executeGetItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1869)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.getItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1840)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.internal.GetItemImpl.doLoadItem(GetItemImpl.java:77)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.internal.GetItemImpl.getItemOutcome(GetItemImpl.java:40)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.internal.GetItemImpl.getItemOutcome(GetItemImpl.java:99)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.internal.GetItemImpl.getItem(GetItemImpl.java:111)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Table.getItem(Table.java:624)
at com.amazonaws.lambda.service.TokenValidatorService.retrieveItemFromDB(TokenValidatorService.java:82)
at com.amazonaws.lambda.service.TokenValidatorService.checkToken(TokenValidatorService.java:42)
```

In DynamoDB I have a table with the SAME NAME and REGION.I am using the AWS package com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2 to do all the operations.Can anyone help me to solve the issue.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42757872/the-provided-key-element-does-not-match-the-schema-error-when-getting-an-item

Answer (score 3):

> The provided key element does not match the schema

Make sure you provide the right key Name

Comment: in DB I have 2 keys, TokenId ( Note : Primary partition key - TokenId (Number)) and Phase and I am trying to access the data using the key, TokenId. What is the error in it ?

Comment: Key can be a Map if you have 2 keys

Comment: Not sure in Java, but I have an example in python https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.03.html#GettingStarted.Python.03.02